# multiple callback in the async in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

i am new in node js i stuck in calling multiple callback in waterfall of async method.

```
var offer = new Offer(req.body);
        offer.featured_tag=false;
        var err = '';
        reserror='';
        async.waterfall([
            function (done) {
                if(req.body.create_role === 'Merchant' || req.body.create_role=== 'SubMerchant'){
                    //if offer created by merchant is less than than the subscription of merchant then active this offer when adding otherwise deactive
                    offer.active_immediately=false;
                    Offer.find({ merchant_id:req.body.merchant_id }).populate('merchant_id').exec(function(err, offerscount) {
                        //  count no of offers createdBy merchant
                        console.log(offerscount);
                        var noofrecords=offerscount.length;
                        if(noofrecords>0){
            if(typeof offerscount[0].merchant_id.more_details.fields!=='undefined'){
                            if(offerscount[0].merchant_id.more_details.fields.subscription){
                                if(noofrecords<offerscount[0].merchant_id.more_details.fields.subscription.number_offer){
                                    offer.active_immediately=true;
                                }
                                if(offerscount[0].merchant_id.more_details.fields.subscription.feature_tag === true){
                                    offer.featured_tag=true;
                                }
                            }
                            if(req.body.loyalty_offer==true){
                              Offer.find({ merchant_id:req.body.merchant_id,loyalty_offer:true }).populate('merchant_id').exec(function(err, loyaltyoff) {
                                console.log('count:'+loyaltyoff.length);
                                if(loyaltyoff.length>0){
                                    if(loyaltyoff.length===offerscount[0].merchant_id.more_details.fields.subscription.loyalty_offers){
                                      console.log('hello');
                                /*     reserror = {
                                          "status":0,
                                          "data":"",
                                          "message":"Exceeds the loyalty offers limit."
                                      };*/
                                      reserror = 'Exceeds the loyalty offers limit.';

                                        done(err, reserror);


                                    }
                                }

                             });
                          }
                        }


                              done(err, 'debug1');

                        }
                 }else if(req.body.create_role === 'Admin'){
                    done(null,'debug1')
                 }
            }, function(err, reserror) {
                console.log('load');
                var startdate = new Date(req.body.startdate);
                offer.startdate = startdate.toISOString();
                var enddate = new Date(req.body.enddate);
                offer.enddate = enddate.toISOString();
                offer.createdOn=Date.now();
                offer.createdBy=req.body.creater_id;
                offer.isDeleted= false;
                offer.offer_image=req.body.image;
                console.log('bug'+err);
                if(err!='debug1'){
                  var reserror1 = {
                       "status":0,
                       "data":"",
                       "message":'Exceeds the loyalty offers limit.'
                   };
                   res.json(reserror1);

                }else{
                  offer.save(function(err,data) {
                      if (err) {
                          response = {
                              "status":0,
                              "error":err
                          };
                      }else{
                          Category.findById(req.body.main_cat, function (err, catdataset) {
                              var offerset = {
                                  offer_id: data._id,
                                  posted_by: data.createdBy,
                                  datetime: data.createdOn
                              };
                              catdataset.offers.push(offerset);
                              catdataset.save();
                          });
                          response = {
                              "status":1,
                              "data":data,
                              "message":"Offer has been created."
                          };
                      }
                      console.log(response);
                      res.json(response);
                  });
                }
            }
        ]);
```

in the above code if the **done(err, reserror);** is call after **done(err, 'debug1');**.it does not wait for reserror so i want to check the error first if the reserror is not null or blank then only call **done(err, 'debug1');** otherwise call the  **done(err, reserror);**.please help me to findout the solution.thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code.

```
var offer = new Offer(req.body);
        offer.featured_tag=false;
        var err = '';
        reserror='';
 async.waterfall([
            function (done) {
                if(req.body.create_role === 'Merchant' || req.body.create_role=== 'SubMerchant'){
                    //if offer created by merchant is less than than the subscription of merchant then active this offer when adding otherwise deactive
                    offer.active_immediately=false;
                    Offer.find({ merchant_id:req.body.merchant_id }).populate('merchant_id').exec(function(err, offerscount) {
                        //  count no of offers createdBy merchant
                        console.log(offerscount);
                        var noofrecords=offerscount.length;
                        if(noofrecords>0){
            if(typeof offerscount[0].merchant_id.more_details.fields!=='undefined'){
                            if(offerscount[0].merchant_id.more_details.fields.subscription){
                                if(noofrecords<offerscount[0].merchant_id.more_details.fields.subscription.number_offer){
                                    offer.active_immediately=true;
                                }
                                if(offerscount[0].merchant_id.more_details.fields.subscription.feature_tag === true){
                                    offer.featured_tag=true;
                                }
                            }
                            if(req.body.loyalty_offer==true){
                              Offer.find({ merchant_id:req.body.merchant_id,loyalty_offer:true }).populate('merchant_id').exec(function(err, loyaltyoff) {
                                console.log('count:'+loyaltyoff.length);
                                if(loyaltyoff.length>0){
                                    if(loyaltyoff.length===offerscount[0].merchant_id.more_details.fields.subscription.loyalty_offers){
                                      console.log('inside loyalty');
                                     reserror = {
                                          "status":0,
                                          "data":"",
                                          "message":"Exceeds the loyalty offers limit."
                                      };
                                    //  reserror = 'Exceeds the loyalty offers limit.';

                                      done(err, reserror);
//return res.json(reserror);
//next();

                                    }else{
                                      done(err, 'debug1');
                                    }
                                }else{
                                  done(err, 'debug1');
                                }

                             });
                          }else{
                            done(err, 'debug1');
                          }
                        }else{
                          done(err, 'debug1');
                        }

                 }else if(req.body.create_role === 'Admin'){
                    done(null,'debug1')
                 }
            }, function(err, reserror) {
                console.log('load');
                var startdate = new Date(req.body.startdate);
                offer.startdate = startdate.toISOString();
                var enddate = new Date(req.body.enddate);
                offer.enddate = enddate.toISOString();
                offer.createdOn=Date.now();
                offer.createdBy=req.body.creater_id;
                offer.isDeleted= false;
                offer.offer_image=req.body.image;
                console.log('bug'+err);
                if(err!='debug1'){
                  var reserror1 = {
                       "status":0,
                       "data":"",
                       "message":'Exceeds the loyalty offers limit.'
                   };
                   return res.json(reserror1);

                }else{
                  offer.save(function(err,data) {
                      if (err) {
                          response = {
                              "status":0,
                              "error":err
                          };
                      }else{
                          Category.findById(req.body.main_cat, function (err, catdataset) {
                              var offerset = {
                                  offer_id: data._id,
                                  posted_by: data.createdBy,
                                  datetime: data.createdOn
                              };
                              catdataset.offers.push(offerset);
                              catdataset.save();
                          });
                          response = {
                              "status":1,
                              "data":data,
                              "message":"Offer has been created."
                          };
                      }
                      console.log(response);
                      res.json(response);
                  });
                }
            }
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use different name for error. Let say that below service error name is err1 and the top service  error name is err

```
Offer.find({ merchant_id:req.body.merchant_id,loyalty_offer:true })
              .populate('merchant_id').exec(function(err1, loyaltyoff) {

  if(loyaltyoff.length>0){

   if(loyaltyoff.length===
            offerscount[0].merchant_id.more_details.fields.subscription.loyalty_offers){
        console.log('hello');
        reserror = 'Exceeds the loyalty offers limit.';

        if (reserror !== null && reserror !== undefined) {
            done(err, 'debug1');
        } else {
            done(err1, reserror);
        }

   }
 });
```

Comment: Oh. But you said "i want to check the error first if the reserror is not null or blank then only call done(err, 'debug1'); otherwise call the done(err, reserror)"

Comment: yes but in above your code see first it check the condition of the loyaltyoff.length if it is true then it call the done(err1, reserror).see my code you get an idea that loyaltyoff.length is not greater than 0 then ..